# Unity 3d crashing on mac when I press "play" in the editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I downloaded Unity 3d on my macbook air and created a new project with a single 3d object (a plane).

When I press the "play" button (Triangle icon), unity hangs and crashes.

It happens no matter if I create a new project again and add a different 3d object (a sphere).

The only way my project doesnt crash when I press play is if it's a completely blank project with no 3d objects.

Interestingly I can build a mac build of a project and it runs okay (I can see the 3d objects, the plane or the sphere).

Can anyone offer any advice?

Edit: OS / X version 10.9

Comment: try to reinstall unity. It is running well for me on macbook pro with latest osx

Comment: There is a patch version 5.1.2p1 in which they have fixed this bug, as they say in fixes list:

OS X: Fixed building on OS X El Capitan.

What is your unity version ?

Comment: check crash logs in `~/Library/Logs/Unity`. it might provide information about that.

Comment: Ill check the exact version when I get home, it's the most recent - 5.6.1, and I'll also look in the logs. I suspect it's a rendering issue since it only crashes when there is a 3d object.

Comment: Ok Im upgrading OSX from 10.9 to 10.12...

Comment: @vikingsteve just upvote the comment, should be fine I thing

Answer (score 0):

My version of OS/X was a little outdated.

Upgrading from 10.9 to 10.12.X fixed the problem (after a 4 GB download and 60 minute install)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think i solved it. My project settings had metal editor support disabled. Enabling this option solved the crashing problem. I reproduced this issue with a freshly created project and just disabled the Metal editor support. I tried on a macbook pro 2018 (with dedicated graphics card) and could not reproduce the issue. This could be an Intel graphics driver related problem.